# Como enviar valores da Activity para webview cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova

Como eu faço para enviar dados da Activity e resgatar na WebView com javascript da index.html do cordova/Phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que você já possua sua `WebView` em ação, você pode executar um método *JavaScript* dentro dela assim:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:foo('" + bar + "')");
```

E dentro do **index.html** tem a implementação do método `foo()`, recebendo um parâmetro.

Comment: Ok @Paulo Rodrigues! funcionou belezinha, muito obrigado.